# Best NLP tool for Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, nlp, bigdata, nltk

I wish to build a NLP based application on Apache Spark which is focused on extracting keyphrases from customer reviews and based on that finding the sentiments of each keyphrase. Can anyone help me in deciding the best NLP tool for spark ? I have used NLTK(natural Language Toolkit) in Spark and looking for a better one.

Comment: well, for what task of NLP? doc. classification? information extraction? clustering documents?

Comment: Creating an ETL which focusses mostly on extracting keywords from paragraphs and getting the sentiments out of it. For example extracting keywords from a customer review and then getting sentiment out of it.

Comment: "extracting keywords from a customer review and then getting sentiment out of it", you mean keywords are attributes or characteristics of a product, and then you want to infer the sentiment over each of these attributes, as in, Aspect-based Sentiment Analysis?

Comment: exactly,based on the keywords I want to infer sentiments

Comment: ok, so first suggestion, why not edit your question accordingly, and being specific about what you want and then that you want do to it at large-scale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to try Spark-NLP, and use a combination of the TextMatcher and the Sentiment Detector-
More docs here,
https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/components.html

best,
Alberto.